# How to change the style of ToC and \chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to adapt the style and content of my ToC, but I'ma little bit stuck with the tocloft package ^^ e.g., how to set the horizontal ruler? Do I change the command that is used in the ToC or do I add this in my latex document? (see page 5 "To add a horizontal line across the whole width of the ToC below an entry for a Part:...")

*It should look like this:*

**CHAPTER N**

**Title of my chapter**

---

N.M  Title of my section .......... pagenumber

N.M  Title of my section .......... pagenumber

*Variation:*

Chapter N | **Title of my chapter**

---

N.M  Title of my section .......... pagenumber

N.M  Title of my section .......... pagenumber

Additionally, I would like to change the font family of the chapters within the ToC and the document itself, as well.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible solution (feel free to adapt it according to your needs); the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package was used to change the formatting for chapter entries in the ToC and the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package was used to change the formatting for chapter headings in the document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\\\hspace*{\dimexpr-\mylen-1.5em\relax}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{0em}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{%
  \par\vskip-1ex\hspace*{\dimexpr-\mylen-1.5em\relax}\hrulefill\par}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\sffamily}
\chapterfont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to adapt your code, but I'm kind of lost :-( I searched the documentation at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft, but can't find explanations for the commands like cftchapaftersnumb. Now I would like to write "Chapter x" in normal font, followed by a "|" and the chapter name in bold, without a new line. How can I access the chapter name?