# Horizontal line under chapters in a multicolumn ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, rules

I have a document that contains a multicolumn ToC made with

```
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{3}
```

I use the following command to make chapters and add them to the ToC, as I do not want chapter numbers to show up anywhere:

```
\newcommand{\myChapter}[1]{
  \chapter*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}
```

I want to add a line under each chapter heading in this ToC, but I simply cannot figure out how to do it. It should end up looking like this:

```
Chapter 1               1.1.3 Subsection        2.1.1 Subsection
-----------------                               2.1.2 Subsection
1.1 Section             Chapter 2
1.1.1 Subsection        -----------------
1.1.2 Subsection        2.1 Section
```

I have looked at the [tocloft](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and it gives an example for parts:

```
\part{Part title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
```

This works, but I am interested in doing it for chapters, not parts. I have looked at [Overfull hbox (in the middle of page) in ToC with tocloft package and cftchapaftersnum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2888/overfull-hbox-in-the-middle-of-page-in-toc-with-tocloft-package-and-cftchapaft) and [How to change the style of ToC and \chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70126/how-to-change-the-style-of-toc-and-chapter) and followed the answers, without success. The line simply does not show up.

Can anyone tell me how I can make these lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\addtocontents` to add the rule:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}

\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{3}

\newcommand{\myChapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-6pt\par\noindent\protect\hrulefill\par}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\myChapter{A test chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\myChapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\myChapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Something that I don't quite understand is that you don't want chapter number to appear, but your example shows the chapter counter before the sections.